# How to run two loops in one mysql query with php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi friends I have a two array
One is from database

```
$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
          $alluser = $row1['user_id'];
```

And another one is Associative array

```
 $inputArray["NoContact"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='100'";
 $inputArray["Contacted"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='200'";
 $inputArray["Qualifying"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='300'";
 $inputArray["Submitted"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='400'";
 $inputArray["Interviewing"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='500'";
 $inputArray["Offered"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='600'";
 $inputArray["ClientDeclined"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='700'";
 $inputArray["Placed"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='800'";
 $inputArray["NoStatus"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='0'";
 $inputArray["NotInConsideration"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='650'";
 $inputArray["Candidate Responded"] = " and candidate_joborder.status='250'";
```

Here MYSQL query like this:

```
SELECT count(candidate_joborder.joborder_id) as counts FROM candidate_joborder JOIN joborder ON joborder.joborder_id = candidate_joborder.joborder_id where candidate_joborder.added_by= $alluser and candidate_joborder.status = $inputArray
```

Here i am in need of like this

```
<table border =1>
  <tr>
    <th>user name</th> 
    <th>No_Contact</th>
    <th>Contacted</th>
    <th>Qualifying</th>
    <th>Submitted</th>
    <th>Interviewing</th>
    <th>Offered</th>
    <th>Client_Declined</th>
    <th>Placed</th>
    <th>No_Status</th>
    <th>Not in Consideration</th>
    <th>Candidate_Responded</th>
  </tr>
```

And columns and Rows are executing  based on the query

**Also in the User name column would contain the $alluser values**
Here i've tried with **PHP Foreach** but i could't get any idea as well as now ***PLEASE HELP ME*** any one

Here I am using foreach loop to get the associative array value my code is below It's working for associative array only

```
foreach($inputArray as $x => $x_value)
        {
            //concatenates the SQL query with its status through the temporary variable
                $temp = $sql . $x_value;
            //executes the sql query and returns the resultset
                $resultSet = mysqli_query($con,$temp);
            //assigns the returned rows in the resultset to the variable using the mysqli_fetch_array()
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet);
            //assigns the count to the second array for all the status using the index
                $outputArray[$x]=$row['counts'];
        }

        echo "<table align = center border =1><tr>";
        //foreach loop which loops through outputArray
        foreach($outputArray as $x => $x_value)
        {
            echo '<th>'.$x .'</th>';
        }
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        //foreach loop which loops through outputArray
        foreach($outputArray as $x)
        {
            echo '<td>'.$x .'</td>';
        }

        echo "</tr></table>";
```

**Actually here i am concatenating MYSQL query using $sql variable** ***Here i am concatenating $sql without $alluser***  Like mysql

```
SELECT candidate_joborder.joborder_id as counts,joborder.title as title FROM candidate_joborder JOIN joborder ON joborder.joborder_id = candidate_joborder.joborder_id where candidate_joborder.status= **$x_value**
```

Comment: Your code makes NO sense. you define an array, then stuff that array into your query string. arrays in string context become the literal word `Array`, so your query is doing `... and job_status = Array`.

Comment: We do not need HTML, we need some more PHP code and show us what IN PHP the result you are expecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a single row returned with the counts of each status in that row.

If so it can be done something like this:-

```
SELECT SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='100', 1, 0)) AS NoContact,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='200', 1, 0)) AS Contacted,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='300', 1, 0)) AS Qualifying,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='400', 1, 0)) AS Submitted,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='500', 1, 0)) AS Interviewing,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='600', 1, 0)) AS Offered,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='700', 1, 0)) AS ClientDeclined,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='800', 1, 0)) AS Placed,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='0', 1, 0)) AS NoStatus,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='650', 1, 0)) AS NotInConsideration,
        SUM(IF(candidate_joborder.status='250', 1, 0)) AS Candidate Responded
FROM candidate_joborder 
JOIN joborder 
ON joborder.joborder_id = candidate_joborder.joborder_id 
WHERE candidate_joborder.added_by= $alluser
```

But this does seem rather pointless for a single user, and it would be better to bring back multiple rows, one for each status and loop around the results:-

```
SELECT candidate_joborder.status, 
        COUNT(*) 
FROM candidate_joborder 
JOIN joborder 
ON joborder.joborder_id = candidate_joborder.joborder_id 
WHERE candidate_joborder.added_by= $alluser 
AND candidate_joborder.status IN ('100', 200','300', '400', '500', '600', '700', '800', '0', '650', '250')
GROUP BY candidate_joborder.status
```

Answer (score 0):

Both arrays are in PHP (whether they are filled from DB or not is irrelevant), which is on server side, and you need to form HTML code (executed in client side).

Use `foreach` in order to iterate the arrays needed, then form your HTML output using `echo`.